# Cannot run command inside bash variable including square brackets with nullglob

Tags: bash, environment-variables, quoting, wildcards

Assuming I want to run commnand stored inside the variable with nullglob turned on. For example:

```
shopt -s nullglob
a="echo [foo]bar"
${a}
```

This gives me an empty output due to the nullglob option of course, but I want the following output (which I am not able to get):

```
[foo]bar
```

I tried escaping [] with \ but that just gives me:

```
\[foo\]bar
```

What is the correct way of escaping it?

EDIT (clarification with some context):

I have a script like this:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in tmp/*.pdb; do
    base="$(basename ${file} .pdb)"
    a="command --option [${base}]foo"
    ${a}
done
shopt -u nullglob
```

What I wanted to achieve is to run command for each file with an option which has [] as ordinary characters (without any matching). The nullglob here was used just for the for loop.

That is if "tmp" contains "a.pdb" run:

```
command --option '[a]foo'
```

and nothing if no such file is present.

In a meantime I figured out that moving "shopt -u nullglob" as the first command in the for loop seems to solve the problem. However, I am curious if I can somehow escape the [] even with nullglob.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I'd misunderstood. Could you clarify what output you expect if i) there is a file matching `[foo]bar` and ii) if there isn't?

Comment: Also, you seem to be attempting to recreate the behavior of the shell without `nullglob`. Why not just unset `nullglob`? What am I missing?

Comment: @terdon I guess the original question wasn't clear at all, sorry. :-) I added some clarification.

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes more sense :) See updated answer, does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, read [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ#BashFAQ.2F050.I.27m_trying_to_put_a_command_in_a_variable.2C_but_the_complex_cases_always_fail.21).

Then, define a function:

```
a () {
    echo "[foo]bar"
}
```

For your script, there is no reason to put the command in a variable first anway; just run the command.

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in tmp/*.pdb; do
    base="$(basename ${file} .pdb)"
    command --option "[${base}]foo"
done
shopt -u nullglob
```

If you *must* store something in variables, separate the command from its options, and use an array to hold the options.

```
shopt -s nullglob
cmd=command
for file in tmp/*.pdb; do
    base="$(basename ${file} .pdb)"
    options=( --option "[${base}]foo" )
    "$cmd" "${options[@]}"
done
shopt -u nullglob
```

Comment: The purpose of having all of this in a variable was to write it to the log if command fails. However, since command is the always the same, logging the options is sufficient (which I didn't realize earlier) and the array approach you mentioned works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you're saving the command as a variable. Why not do something like what I show below and avoid the problem?

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in tmp/*.pdb; do
    base="$(basename ${file} .pdb)"
    command --option "[${base}]foo"
done
shopt -u nullglob
```

Alternatively, if you need the command in a variable for other reasons, you could remove the `nullglob` and just make sure that files exist before running the command:

```
for file in tmp/*.pdb; do
  if [ -e "$file" ]; then
        base="$(basename ${file} .pdb)"
        a="command --option [${base}]foo"
        ${a}
done
```

It's rarely a good idea to save commands as variables. Another approach would be to save the *options* as variables instead:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in tmp/*.pdb; do
    base="$(basename ${file} .pdb)"
    a="--option [${base}]foo"
    command "$a"
done
shopt -u nullglob
```